# Bounding the Eigenvalues of a Scaled Covariance Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, covariance

Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$ be a data matrix where $n \geq p$.

Say that I know that the covariance matrix $$X^T X$$ has $n$ real eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$.

Is it possible to produce a lower bound and/or upper bound on the eigenvalues of a scaled covariance matrix:

$$X^T D X$$

Here $D$ is a $n\times n$ diagonal "scaling" matrix with $d_1,\ldots,d_n$ on the diagonal. The elements $d_1,\ldots,d_n$ are real, positive, and bounded in the interval $[d_{min},d_{max}]$ where $0 < d_{min} < d_{max} < 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Upper Bound:**

Let $\rho$ denote the maximal eigenvalue of $X^TX$.  Let $\|A\|$ denote the spectral norm of the matrix $A$, given by $\|A\| = \lambda_{max}(\sqrt{A^TA})$. We then have
$$
\|X^TDX\| \leq \|X^T\|\cdot \|D\| \cdot \|X\|
$$
On the other hand, we have
$$
\|X\| = \sqrt{\rho}\\
\|X^T\| = \lambda_{max}(\sqrt{XX^T}) = 
\lambda_{max}(\sqrt{X^TX}) = \sqrt{\rho}\\
\|D\| = \lambda_{max}(D) \leq 1
$$
So, all together, we have
$$
\lambda_{max}(X^TDX) \leq \|X^TDX\| \leq \|X^T\|\cdot \|D\| \cdot \|X\| \leq \rho
$$

---

**Lower Bound:**

First of all, note that $X^TDX$ is positive semidefinite, so its eigenvalues are certainly non-negative.

Let $d = d_{min}$.  We note that the matrix
$$
X^TDX - d(X^TX) = X^T(D - dI)X
$$
is necessarily positive definite.  It follows that 
$$
\lambda_{min}(X^TDX) \geq \lambda_{min}(dX^TX) = d\lambda_{min}(X^TX)
$$
In fact, we could also have used this trick for the upper bound by noting that $X^T(\rho I - D)X$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: Thanks! I see why $X^T X$ and $X^T X D$ are positive definite, but I don't see why $X^T X D X$ is positive definite. Was that just a typo?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo.  Also, $X^TDX$, not $X^TXD$.